# Editing of comment after flagging

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

Suppose:

1. I flag an abusive comment
2. The person who posted that comment edited out the abusive part.

**How will a moderator be able to determine if the comment was abusive in the first place?**

---

Suggested Remedy:

Save a copy of the original comment in the server and then report that text to the moderator.

OR

Prevent editing of a comment after it has been flagged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderators can actually see comment histories along with the fact that it's been edited (which everyone can see).

If you flag a comment that is later edited and that flag is declined, feel free to raise a "something else" flag and explain the situation and ask that the moderator look at the history of the comment.

That said, how a moderator will respond to the second flag may vary and you may not be aware of whether any action was taken or not. Moderators can not respond to comment flags the way they can to post flags and if the comment is no longer abusive (and is actually useful) it probably won't be deleted, so your flag may still be declined, since marking a comment flag "helpful" also deletes the comment.

Comment: Why the down vote? How can I improve this question?

Comment: I didn't cast the vote on your question, so I'm not sure. Feature requests get downvotes when people disagree with them, so that's a possible explanation. Your question also makes some incorrect assumptions... it might be better phrased as a support question asking whether moderators can see edit histories of comments rather than for implementation of a feature that already exists... and what to do if a flag on an edited comment is declined.

Comment: @Caija Thanks for the clarificaation. :)

Comment: "If you flag a comment that is later edited and that flag is declined, feel free to raise a "something else" flag and explain the situation" Why? Why would the situation need to be explained? Flags help with moderating. If the content no longer needs moderation, there is no second flag required.

Comment: @Mast There's no way to know the full story or degree of abuse based on the question. If someone is doing this repeatedly, particularly towards a specific user or group of users, or they are posting particularly extreme comments and then editing them, it's concerning. Editing out abusive content doesn't make posting it in the first place acceptable. But mods can't act on it if they're unaware.

Comment: Fair point, I hadn't considered that type of comment abuse.